# Moving the position of a caret?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically what I'm trying to do is move this caret up and I wouldn't even know where to start, so here's a picture of what I'm trying to move up. (the caret is the little down arrow just in case you didn't know).

[image]

Sorry about the title of this question, it's not very clear but I didn't know what else to call it...

Here's the CSS for the caret in bootstrap

```
.caret {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 4px solid;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the code that produces it, styles it and positions it...we cannot even **begin** to advise you.

Comment: I would suggest that you try and produce an example demo for us...perhaps in [**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/)

Answer (score -1):

I changed the the vertical align which is seen in the code. Instead of

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

I used

```
vertical-align: super;
```

which raised it up to the height of the text.

Comment: Not really. You might want to update your answer as what you specifically changed and **WHY** it had the effect that it did.